# How to prove given points are not on a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Tho points in the plane corresponding to $(-2,5)$ and $(-5,2)$ lie on
>   a line through the origin.

I'm solving some exercise problems and encountered this true/false problem. I took a look the solution, but there was no specific equation or other explanation.

How can I prove these points are not on a line through the origin?

Comment: Two points determine a line! Did you determine the equation of the line passing through these two points?  Then check if the origin $(0,0)$ is on the line (does it satisfy the equation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume it were true.
Any line going through the origin must have the form

$$
y = kx
$$
(-2,5) lies on this line $\Rightarrow$

$$
5 = -2k \Leftrightarrow k = \frac{5}{-2}
$$

So we have 
$$
y = \frac{-5}{2}x
$$

The point $(-5,2)$ doesn't lie on this line, contradiction.

A faster method would (maybe) to do it graphically.

Comment: Clear explanation! Then, do I not have to consider about "plane"?

Comment: I dont understand your question. @baeharam

Comment: I mean, why this problem includes word "plane"? Is it related to span?

Comment: No, it just tells use that that the space we are working in is the normal $1$-dimensional space. Like if you were to draw the function $f(x) = x^2$ you would draw in the **plane** with an $x$-axis and an $f(x)$-axis.

Comment: I understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Find the equation of the line in the 2-point form. Substitute $0$ for either x or y. Either y or x will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods.  The line through the origin and (-2,5) has slope -5/2.  The line through the origin and (-5, 2) has slope -2/5.  Those are not the same so they are not the same line.

Another method: Since the line through the  origin and (-5, 2) has slope -2/5, its equation is y= (-2/5)x or 5y+ 2x= 0.  Setting x= -2 and y= 5 we have 5(5)- 2(-2)= 21, not 0 so (-2, 5) is not on that line.